# Behaviour between two components sending from method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very strange problem.
I have component A and service B.
From A component I send the object to the service  B. In B service that object I push in tho the array and after changes data from my Array I have changed into the A component.

Lest start:
I A component I have the array `returnedArray: ProductModel[] = [];` with some data.
And in the template, I have `ngFor`  `*ngFor="let products of returnedArray; let i = index">`

And from this button I call the method:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"


(click)="addToShoppingList(products)">
               addd
                <span class="op-icon op-shopping-cart"></span>
            </button>
```

This is code of method:

```
 addToShoppingList(product: ProductModel) {

        this.shop.setProductCart(product);
            this.messageService.add('Proizvod je dodat u korpu!!!');

    }
```

My `setProductCart` is in the `ShopCartService`:

```
setProductCart(product: ProductModel) {

   for (let i = 0; i < this.productCart.length; i++) {
        if (this.productCart[i].product_name == product.product_name) {
            this.productCart[i].numberOfProduct++;
        }

    }
    this.productCart.push(product);

}
```

This is my array productCart

```
private productCart: ProductModel[] = []
```

Problem is when I execute this`this.productCart[i].numberOfProduct++;` I have changes in the A component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing `product` object to service, you are passing a reference to the object.

So, any changes made to the object in the service are reflected in the component.

To prevent this, instead of passing a reference, pass a copy of the object.

```
 this.shop.setProductCart({...product});
```

I'm using ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a copy. We also have [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method and several others ways to clone an object.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome @SInsansun. Verify if it is working and let me know if you have any questions.